# Order datagridview descending with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I try to order my datagridview but can't. On the web I found and modified this:

```
 List<DataGridViewRow> q = (from item in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            orderby item.Cells[0].Value descending
                            select item).ToList<DataGridViewRow>();
```

But it doesn't work because I don't know how to assign this list to the datasource of my datagridview.

Maybe, it is not the correct form to do this. In other projects I put the data on my datagridview in a list and then I execute the linq query on my list and it's works. How is it in datagridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
List<DataGridViewRow> q = (from item in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            orderby item.Cells[0].Value descending
                            select item).ToList<DataGridViewRow>();

dataGridView1.DataSource = q.Select(x => x.DataBoundItem).Cast<Employee>().ToList();
```

For cast I have passed `Employee` but you need to pass your class instead of `Employee`

Or you can bind datasource without cast, like

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = q.Select(x => x.DataBoundItem).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `DataGridView.Sort()` method:

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

If you decide to use LINQ (maybe more complex ordering, or manipulating the data in some other way), it'd be preferable to act on the original source of data (i.e. a list), like you said you've done before.

I don't think you can do what you want to do in a generic sort of way, because `DataSource` is an `object`, so eventually you'll need to cast `DataSource` back to whatever the original data type was that you used to populate the `DataGridView` with in the first place.

Comment: yes, this is not the best example. sorry. anyway, can i assig to the datasource a list<datagridviewRow> ?